disable and enable power monitor usb via cmd
I am using power monitor to test current, and I want to do some simple testing via automated commands
Before test, I need to send some cmd to machine via usb, then the current test need remove usb（When connected to USB, the machine will be charged, affecting the results）
but I do not know to to disable or enable the usb port via python or cmd and it will disconnect the usb charge power
thx for help

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
